# Delete Files Without Popup's Using Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am using the below code to delete the contents of a folder, the only issue I have now is that if 1 of the files is in use, it pops a confirmation dialog, and then starts showing the progress to the user of the software.

Since these are temp files user's are completely baffled by the popup and keep asking about it.

Is there some way to tweak it, so that if a file is in use or cannot be deleted, that the code will just move on to the next file and ignore this one until the next attempt.

**Code**

```
procedure DelFilesFromDir(Directory, FileMask: string; DelSubDirs: Boolean);
var
  SourceLst: string;
  FOS: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  FillChar(FOS, SizeOf(FOS), 0);
  FOS.Wnd := Application.MainForm.Handle;
  FOS.wFunc := FO_DELETE;
  SourceLst := Directory + '\' + FileMask + #0;
  FOS.pFrom := PChar(SourceLst);
  if not DelSubDirs then
    FOS.fFlags := FOS.fFlags OR FOF_FILESONLY;
  FOS.fFlags := FOS.fFlags OR FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;
  SHFileOperation(FOS);
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to avoid showing any dialog when an error is encountered, you should add `FOF_NOERRORUI` as an additional flag.

Also, if you want to hide information about the file operation progress entirely, you can add the `FOF_NO_UI` flag instead.

You can read more about the possible flags in the official [`SHFileOperation()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795.aspx).

Comment: What will happen if I change the `FOF_NOCONFIRMATION` to `FOF_NO_UI` as per your suggestion should the file it is trying to delete be locked by another operation?

Comment: @Marcel There's nothing like trying something out to learn more about it. ;)

Comment: @Marcel: "FOF_NO_UI
Windows Vista. Perform the operation silently, presenting no UI to the user. This is equivalent to FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR." from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-_shfileopstructa)